# Exception Handling Java

Tags: java

```
class chain_exceptions{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      try
      {
         f1();
      }
      catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
      {
         System.out.println("A");
         throw new NullPointerException(); //Line 0
      }
      catch(NullPointerException e) //Line 1
      {
         System.out.println("B");
         return;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         System.out.println("C");
      }
      finally
      {
         System.out.println("D");
      }
      System.out.println("E");
   }

   static void f1(){
      System.out.println("Start...");
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException( "parameter" );
   }
}
```

I expected the Line 1 to catch the NullPointerException thrown from the Line 0 but it does not happen.

But why so ?.

When there is another catch block defined, why cant the NPE handler at Line1 catch it ?

Is it because the "throw" goes directly to the main() method ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception thrown inside catch block - will it be caught again?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143622/exception-thrown-inside-catch-block-will-it-be-caught-again)

Comment: You should read a bit about the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779285/exception-thrown-in-catch-and-finally-clause

Comment: In case you're curious, you can find the details in the Java specification [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.3).

Comment: Exceptions are caught by a *nested* block, not a block at a the same level.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Catch{ . . . }` blocks are associated with `try{ . . . }` blocks. **A `catch` block can catch exceptions that are thrown from a try block only**. The other catch blocks after first catch block are not associated with a try block and hence when you throw an exception, they are not caught. Or `main()` does not catch exceptions.

A kind of this for each catch block will do what you are trying to do.

```
try{
  try
  {
     f1();
  }
  catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
  {
     System.out.println("A");
     throw new NullPointerException(); //Line 0
  }
}
catch(NullPointerException e) //Line 1
{
     System.out.println("B");
     return;
}
```

Comment: lol, yes. I think OP just want to know what can solve his problem.

Answer (score 3):

The catch blocks are only for the try block. They won't catch exceptions from other catch blocks.

Answer (score 3):

`catch` statements only catch exceptions thrown from a `try { ... }` block.

The `NullPointerException` is thrown from a `catch { ... }` block, not a `try { ... }` block.

To catch an exception thrown from a `catch` block you need to put *another* `try` block inside of it.  Outside, wrapping the original `try...catch` would work, too.

Answer (score 2):

A second `catch` doesn't catch the exception from the first `catch` block. You have to add another `try-catch` **within** the first `catch` block (or **around** the whole `try-catch` you already have) to make this run as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Since java 7 you can use code below or an other option is to nest the try catch statements, there is no other option in java

```
try { 
 ...
} catch( indexoutofboundsexception| nullpointerexception ex ) { 
  logger.log(ex);
  throw ex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `catch` clauses only catch exceptions thrown by `f1()`. They don't call exceptions thrown in other `catch` clauses of the same try-catch-finally construct.

Answer (score 1):

Because `f1()` throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
try
      {
         f1(); //throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
      }
      catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) //gets caught here immediately and does not check other catch blocks
      {
         System.out.println("A");
         throw new NullPointerException(); //Line 0
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes, the `throw` will directly throw the exception to the main method.

Generally, once a `catch` block is executed, it behaves like an `else if`, that is, it won't consider the other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

No, the reason it isn't being caught is because it isn't in the try block which is linked to the catch block. If you want to catch that exception as well, you would have to wrap the throw in a new try/catch group. The reason why you would want to do this tho, is a riddle to me.

What you also can do btw:

```
catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException|NullPointerException e)
```

This will also allow you to use the same catch block for multiple types of exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation was incorrect:

The `catch` blocks are associated with the `try` block. So once an exception is thrown inside of the `try`, it **leaves** that scope. Now you are in the scope *outside* the `try`, meaning you are no longer in any `try`/`catch` block. Any exceptions thrown here (when you re-`throw`) will not be caught by anything, and yes, bubble out of `main`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not `catch` exception from another `catch` block, for that you probably need to do something like this, in your first catch block

```
System.out.println("A");
try{
     throw new NullPointerException(); //Line 0
}    
catch(NullPointerException e) //Line 1
{      
     System.out.println("B");
     return;
}
```