# How to catch user input if it is anything else but int?

Tags: java, error-handling

so I am creating a TicTacToe game right now and don't really know how to handle anything else but a int. Let's say the user input is a string - the program would throw a error. I actually want it to catch it and say something like "this is not a number between 1 and 9". How can I do this?

```
int nextPlayerTurn= scan.nextInt();
            while (playerPosition.contains(nextPlayerTurn) ||computerPosition.contains(nextPlayerTurn)
                    || nextPlayerTurn>= 10 || nextPlayerTurn<= 0 ) {
                System.out.println("Position already taken! Please input a valid number (between 1 and 9) ");
                nextPlayerTurn= scan.nextInt();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle infinite loop caused by invalid input (InputMismatchException) using Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572160/how-to-handle-infinite-loop-caused-by-invalid-input-inputmismatchexception-usi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `try catch` method or `if else` conditions.
 
using `if else`,

```
if(scan.hasNextInt()){
    int nextPlayerTurn = scan.nextInt();
    if(nextPlayerTurn < 0 || nextPlayerTurn > 10){
        System.out.println("this is not a number between 1 and 9");
    }else{
        //do something
    }
}else{
    System.out.println("this is not a number between 1 and 9");
}
```

using `try catch`,

```
try{
    int nextPlayerTurn = scan.nextInt();
    if(nextPlayerTurn < 0 || nextPlayerTurn > 10){
        System.out.println("this is not a number between 1 and 9");
    }else{
        //do something
    }
}catch(InputMismatchException e){
    System.out.println("this is not a number between 1 and 9");
}
```

However, you can also use a method to check the `InputMismatchException`.
Also check [Exception Handling Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608217/exception-handling-java/18608262)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `nextInt()` and user enters a String, InputMismatchException will be thrown.

This is a way to handle it:

```
try {
    scan.nextInt();
}catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.err.println("this is not a number between 1 and 9");
}
```

Note that you will have to reuse `nextInt()` until the user enters an int