# Second catch breaks compilation (first doesn't)

Tags: java, compilation

I have this code:

```
try {
//  if (false) { //(need to add this, otherwise it doesn't compile)
//      throw new CountDownExc(-1);
//  }

    return ad2;
} catch (StackOverflowExc | NoClassDefFoundError e) {
    throw new CountDownExc(50);
} catch (CountDownExc e) {
    if (!e.surfaced()) {
        e.dec();
        throw e;
    }
    return 0.0;
}
```

And if I don't add the commented code it doesn't compile with a:

> error: exception CountDownExc is never thrown in body of corresponding
> try statement

Why?

Most of all, why does the first catch doesn't cause the compiler to complain (but the second block seems to be wrong)

Comment: "CountDownExc is never thrown in body of corresponding **try** statement" emphasis should explain why it doesn't like it there. About the fact that it complains only about `CountDownExc` I suppose `CountDownExc` is a checked exception, while the other two aren't

Comment: I think you expect the throw in the first catch to make the second catch valid? If so, then no, all the catches refer just to what's in the `try` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of problems with your code:

1. First and foremost you need to understand the difference between checked exceptions and unchecked exceptions: [Understanding checked vs unchecked exceptions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/understanding-checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java)

Essentially you need to consider checked exceptions as part of your logic and you can only either rethrow them or handle them via `catch`. The only other option if you need to avoid `catch( CountDownExc )` is to add a `throws CountDownExc` declaration to your method.

2. These lines make little sense to me:

```
} catch (StackOverflowExc | NoClassDefFoundError e) {
    throw new CountDownExc(50);
```

It looks like you intend on catching two exception types in the first `catch` block, throw `CountDownExc` in that first catch block, then handle it in the second `catch` block. That's not gonna fly, because `catch` blocks handle what is thrown in a `try` block, not in a `catch` block. Since `CountDownExc` is a checked exception this is going to result in another compilation error, unless you either wrap your `try`-`catch` in another `try`-`catch` (bad practice)  or add a `throws` declaration.

- See: [Exception thrown inside catch block - will it be caught again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143622/exception-thrown-inside-catch-block-will-it-be-caught-again)

Since both of your `catch`es throw `CountDownExc` the exception will have to be handled elsewhere anyway, so this may already be accounted for - I cannot tell, because the rest of your code is unknown.

Your immediate problem however comes from the fact, that nothing in your `try` block is able to throw `CountDownExc` and `CountDownExc` is a checked exception, see first link.